# bpfilter status in 5.4+ mainline Linux kernel as of 2021

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, ubuntu-20.04, bpf

What is the status of bpfilter in the 5.4+ mainline Linux kernel as of 2021? If so how would I enable or install it on Ubuntu 20.04 and what command would I use for bpfilter. I can't seem to find a good answer on the web as of 2021 as most of the articles date back to 2018 and are on the new development at the time. Mainly I'm wondering what's the status of bpfilter in the Linux kernel development and production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, bpfilter is still work in progress, but under active progress. Last news I read were [in a patchset from June 2021](https://lore.kernel.org/r/20210603101425.560384-1-me@ubique.spb.ru). 
[Update: [v2 in August 2021](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/20210829183608.2297877-1-me@ubique.spb.ru/), [presentation on the topic at LPC](https://linuxplumbersconf.org/event/11/contributions/940/) in September same year]

As for Linux 5.4, there's not much that you can do with bpfilter. The first components were indeed merged in 2018, but for a long time it was still missing some features (like sleep-able eBPF programs if I remember correctly) required to implement the last parts. Hopefully we'll get something viable in a future release soon.